# How to add meta-data in Android Manifest which is BuildConfig specific?

Tags: android

I have two variants Debug and release.

I have implemented the Facebook SDK for analytics and I want to add the key, one for debug and other for release.

i have defined the resvalue in the configs but not able to set them as meta-data.

Comment: In addition to having `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, also have `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and `src/release/AndroidManifest.xml`. Those latter two need your `<meta-data>` elements plus any parent elements (e.g., `<manifest>`) but do not need the rest of the stuff from `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: So, suppose I want to set the meta-data to the application tag which is different for release and debug. Do I have to write the whole application tag in the latter two Manifest File?

Comment: No. Just have the `<manifest>` (no attributes), `<application>` (no attributes), and your `<meta-data>` element (with all attributes). The contents of `debug` or `release` get merged with `main`, and the manifests will be merged. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge for more.

Comment: In debug Manifest, i have set the fb_app_id like : <application>

        <!-- For fabric -->

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="8914922380090892"/>

    </application>

And I have deleted the meta-data from the main Manifest. While running I am getting enter a valid fb app id. I think the manifest are not merging??

Comment: You can see what your merged manifest looks like by opening a manifest in Android Studio, then clicking on the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab in the manifest editor. Also, do not forget the root `<manifest>` element in your `debug` and `release` manifests.